# Wishlist info.phtml only contains configurable product, not it's simple

Tags: configuration, wishlist

Currently, my wishlist for a clothing store contains configurables with sizes and colors.  When adding a product to the wishlist, only the configurable is passed to the info.phtml, and not it's simple (the size and color chosen).

This defeats the purpose of the wishlist as trying to share this information with friends/family will not show them the exact item you want.

Has anyone ever heard of this problem? I can't seem to find anything about this issue.  Any input is useful.

Comment: have you seen the size and color chosen in info.phtml

Comment: In info.phtml, i run the $product->getData() and check the array to see if price and color availble, but they show up empty.  Meaning it is the configurable parent product showing up @AmitBera

Answer (score 1):

I have checked this for you in one of my demo stores using the default theme. It appears there is a `View Details` link in the Add to Cart column of the wishlist. When you hover this link it reveals the info of the child product that is actually in the wishlist.

[image]

In my case I have added the Ivory White version of the configurable product to my wishlist. The base image of the configurable product is shown (black) along with the name of the configurable product. However there is a link containing the details of the child product.

After sharing the wishlist by sending it to an email address I found out that the recipient of this wishlist email can click the `Add to Cart` link which directly adds the proper variation of the configurable product to the cart. So this seems to work just fine.

[image]

Please note that I have set `System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart > Configurable Product Image` to `Product Thumbnail Itself`.

But there's also a few `View Product` links in this very same wishlist email. When clicking those links the configurable product page will open in the browser. The recipient is unable to determine which variation of the configurable product is desired. So here's definitely some room for improvement...

Comment: I agree with you that there needs to be improvements.  I'd like the recipient of the wishlist to see what kind of color/size the product is before throwing it into their cart.  It just seems kind of sloppy to force the user to add to cart before viewing the simple.  My only guess is to change how the add to wishlist button adds the entire product to the wishlist instead of only the configurable. @ForMat